# How to pass dynamic value in SQL LIKE?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, sql-like

In the below code, I want to pass a dynamic value to SQL-like but receiving.

**CODE**

```
#Database

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="",
    database="deikho_app"
)

cursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)

`videoCatId`=1024

    if videoCatId:
        query = """select * from cb_video where active = 'yes' and status = 'Successful' and category LIKE '%' + %s + '%'"""
        cursor.execute(query, (videoCatId,))
```

**CODE EXPLANATION**

- First of all connection with the database is created.
- Then a value is assigned to `videoCatId` for running if condition.
- After this query is written and stored in the `query` variable.
- And then the query is executed.
- Finally, results are fetched from the database and stored in `seriesResult` variable.

**ERROR**

```
ERROR:dramas-api:Exception on /papis/get-video [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ideation\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Ideation\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Ideation\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Ideation\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "E:\dramas-api.py", line 61, in getVideo
    seriesResult = cursor.fetchall()
  File "C:\Users\Ideation\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 985, in fetchall
    raise errors.InterfaceError("No result set to fetch from.")
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from.
```

Comment: What is `query` variable value?

Comment: @Akina it's SQL statement written right next to it.

Comment: Try ```... LIKE CONCAT('%', %s, '%') ...```

Answer (score 2):

To parameterize values in `LIKE` expressions, incorporate the wildcards in the binded value and not in SQL prepared statement which you can do with Python's F-strings:

```py
query = """select * from cb_video 
           where active = 'yes' 
             and status = 'Successful' 
             and category LIKE %s
        """ 

cursor.execute(query, (f"%{videoCatId}%",))
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Bless you!